# Code Blocks within ext.net scripts or alternative

Tags: .net, extjs, ext.net

How to add code blocks within ext.net for example as :

```
<ext:TextField ID="TextField1" runat="server"   Text="<%= Response.write(varible); %>" >
```

I know this is **not possible** within `xScript` but how to achieve this in **xscript**? or any alternatives ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `<%# %>` databinding syntax which is available on all ASP.NET Controls.

**Example**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Ext.Net" Namespace="Ext.Net" TagPrefix="ext" %>

<script runat="server">
    public string date; 

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!X.IsAjaxRequest)
        {
            this.date = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

            this.TextField1.DataBind();
        }
    }
</script>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />

        <ext:TextField ID="TextField1" runat="server" Text='<%# date %>' />

        <ext:TextField ID="TextField2" runat="server" Text='<%# date %>' AutoDataBind="true" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The `TextField1` component requires the standard code-behind call to `.DataBind()`.

The `TextField2` component takes advantage of the .AutoDataBind property we introduced a while back. Setting `.AutoDataBind="true"` is pretty self explanatory given this sample, but it will automatically call `.DataBind()` for you, so it's not required to explicitly call in code-behind.

Hope this helps.